# Function returns null

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
var result;
  
void searching() async{

  var searchData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('email',isEqualTo: userEmail).get();
  
    setState(() {
      result = searchData.docs.first;
    });
  }

  
void addFollowing(var username , var email , var phoneNumber) async{
  searching();
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(result).collection('following').doc().set({
    'username':username,
    'email':email,
    'phoneNumber':phoneNumber
  });
  print(result);
}
```

I have two function searching and addfollowing . The searching function returns a document that matches the given email and sets the id of that document in result . But it returns null for some reason when i call that fucntion in the addfollowing function .

I am using the add following function on an onTap of a gesturedetector. The first press returns null but the second press returns the data .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the searching is not complete then yet. you need to await it. So change

```
searching();
```

to

```
await searching();
```

Also, I believe you need to change this

```
void searching() async{
```

to this as well

```
Future searching() async{
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This was the solution i was looking for . Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

You should await the searching function in addFollowing to ensure that it completes before you proceed to use the result.

```
void searching() async {
  var searchData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: userEmail).get();
  setState(() {
    result = searchData.docs.first;
  });
}

Future<void> addFollowing(var username, var email, var phoneNumber) async {
  await searching(); // Wait for searching() to complete.
  
  if (result != null) {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(result.id).collection('following').doc().set({
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber
    });
    print(result);
  } else {
    // Handle the case where the user was not found.
    print('User not found.');
  }
}
```